# Failed to open file: Unexpected error when parsing: Failed to read data. Parent error: binary.Read: invalid type uint32

Tags: go

I'm trying to use the following Go package: https://github.com/mrazza/gonav but I'm finding that it works in Go 1.13 but not in 1.14. When I use with 1.14, I receive the following error when trying to parse a file using this code:

code:

```
fNav, ok := os.Open("de_dust2.nav")
if ok != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to open file: %v\n", ok)
    return
}
parserNav := gonav.Parser{Reader: fNav}
mesh, ok := parserNav.Parse()
if ok != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to open file: %v\n", ok)
    return
}
```

error:

```
Failed to open file: Unexpected error when parsing: Failed to read data.
Parent error: binary.Read: invalid type uint32.
```

which I think is occurring in the block of code in `parser.go` that reads as

```
func (p *Parser) read(data interface{}) {
    switch t := data.(type) {
    case *Vector3:
        var x, y, z float32
        p.read(&x)
        p.read(&y)
        p.read(&z)
        *t = Vector3{x, y, z}

    case *bool:
        var b byte
        p.read(&b)
        *t = b > 0

    case *NavDirection:
        var b byte
        p.read(&b)
        *t = NavDirection(b)

    case *NavLadderDirection:
        var i uint32
        p.read(&i)
        *t = NavLadderDirection(i)

    default:
        err := binary.Read(p.Reader, binary.LittleEndian, t)

        if err != nil {
            panic(parserError{"Failed to read data", err})
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the `default` case is being triggered, and `t` is of type `uint32`. Somehow, this is an invalid type for `binary.Read`, but this error was not triggered in previous versions of Go. What is happening here?

Comment: In the default case of the type switch, `t` is `interface{}`. What is the actual type passed into this function?

Comment: Show the code from the calling function where the error is triggered.

Comment: @BurakSerdar it is `uint32`, and I presume it must be `*uint32`?

Comment: Yes, the application is probably passing `uint32` where it should pass `*uint32`.